# Ischaemia and sensitization

Tags: blood, myofascial-pain-syndrome, nociceptor, ischaemia

In Acupuncture, Trigger Points and Musculoskeletal Pain (3rd Edition), Baldry asserts the following:

"When the Myofascial Trigger Point nociceptor-sensitizing substances bradykinin and prostaglandins are released into the tissues as a result of trauma-induced inflammation, they give rise to the development of both vasodilatation and increased vascular permeability.The effect of this is to cause oedema to develop with compression of veins and resultant tissue ischaemia. As a consequence of this a vicious circle is liable to be created because **the ischaemia then leads to the release of still more MTrP nociceptor sensitizing chemical substances**."

Why and how does ischaemia lead to the release of nociceptor sensitizing chemical substances?